# ¿Cómo utilizar include() para leer el contenido de una página con parámetro GET?

Tags: php

Quiero utilizar el `include` de esta forma pero no funciona, ¿alguna solución?

```html
<?php 
 include "http://localhost/peliculas/peliculas.php?buscar=1";
?>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que "no funciona"? ¿Que funcionamiento esperabas? ¿Que código utiliza ese include? Necesitaríamos algo más de información... aunque puedo observar que estás usando `localhost` en la URL. Ten en cuenta que si lo que quieres es utilizarlo en un entorno de producción dicho link no te funcionará.

Comment: que me incluya la pagina php con la variable buscar asignada en la url

Comment: Para eso puedes hacer uso de $_GET['buscar']

Comment: eso  hice pero no funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el PHP que estás intentando ejecutar está en el mismo servidor que tu script actual, se evalúa por la ruta en el sistema de archivos, no por URL. Para un archivo cuya ruta está basada en la raíz de documentos (el root de tu webserver) como `/peliculas/peliculas.php`:

```
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/peliculas/peliculas.php' );
```

Pero querer pasarle un parámetro por GET indica que hay algo *enredado* en tu código. Idealmente le asignarías un valor a una variable, y usarías esa variable en el script que estás evaluando.

De todas formas, siempre se puede recurrir a la forma *rápida y sucia*, que no es lo ideal:

```
$_GET['buscar'] = 1;
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/peliculas/peliculas.php' );
```

---

> **¿Cómo preferiría ordenar el diseño del código?**
>
> Podemos asignarle el valor a una variable en el primer script:
>
> ```
> $buscar = 1;
> include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/peliculas/peliculas.php' );
> ```
>
> Y luego, en `peliculas.php`:
>
> ```
> if (isset($buscar)) {
>     //Se llamó a este script con un include() y se asignó la variable
>     echo "El primer script nos pasó el valor a buscar = $buscar";
> } elseif (isset($_GET['buscar'])) {
>     //Respondiendo directamente a solicitud web
>     $buscar = $_GET['buscar'];
> }
> ```
>
> De esta forma, no sólo tenemos un mejor control por si tuvieramos que
>   emplear lógicas diferentes de acuerdo a si se llamó con un `include()`
>   o si se accedió directamente a la página, sino que también queda claro
>   para poder mantener el código en el futuro, sabiendo que ese script
>   responde a 2 tipos de llamados.

Comment: me funciono lo segundo, pero porque dices que no es lo ideal?

Comment: @OrlandoPasacaRojas es puramente una cuestión de ser prolijo en el código, de tener un buen diseño (no tiene ningún riesgo ni peor performance)... Es decir, si es un script que estás incluyendo, ¿por qué esperarías un parámetro GET como que estuvieras accediendo desde un navegador? En cambio, documentaría en el código de `peliculas.php` que el archivo puede ser llamado, y comprobaría si una variable (por ejemplo `$buscar` ya está definida por el script que lo llama... Ahora agrego algo de esto en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Una solución posible es utilizar la función [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) para leer el contenido de tu URL como un string.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/peliculas/peliculas.php?buscar=1');
```

Otra solución posible es habilitar `allow_url_fopen` o `allow_url_include` en tu `php.ini`.